# Background running

Tags: android, background

I am just starting developping in Android.
I want to implement an application that runs in **background** after activating it from its interface.
In fact, once we activate this application from its menu (and exit the app menu) it should **continously run in background and listen the MIC** (authorization already granted). Once it **detectes a specific voice/noise**, it **generates an ring/song** and **a yes/no box** should be **displayed** in order to allow the user to deactivate the application (deactivate the background service) or keep it running.
I am confusing between the **background APIs**, **which one fits more my case/need** ?

- JobService or
- JobIntentService or
- AsyncTask or
- IntentService or
- etc.,
  Please advise what is the suitable library/API I should use and if there are some examples in this context.

Thanks in advance.
est regards.

---

31 March 2021

Thanks so much for this proposal. In fact, I am trying a simple example to create an empty file based on your code. But the application is crashing and exiting once I call myservice. Below my class (I updated AndroidManifest.xml as suggested). I added some version verification as suggested by Android Studio. Please advise how to fix this issue ?

```
 public class MyService extends Service {

private String tmpPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+ "/temp.wav";



private final IBinder mBinder = (IBinder) new MyBinder();

public MyService() {
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
}

public class MyBinder extends Binder {
    public MyService getService() {
        return MyService.this;
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        initForeGroundService();
    }

    recordWavAudio();

    // startRecord() -- your implement
}


protected  void recordWavAudio() {

    FileOutputStream wavOut = null;
    File wavFile = new File(tmpPath);

    try {
        wavOut = new FileOutputStream(wavFile);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

    }
    if (wavOut != null) {
        try {
            wavOut.close();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ;
        }
    }

}

//@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private void initForeGroundService() {
    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    NotificationChannel nc =
            null;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        nc = new NotificationChannel(
                "myteset",
                getResources().getString(R.string.app_name),
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN);

        nc.enableLights(false);
        nc.enableVibration(false);
        nc.setSound(null, Notification.AUDIO_ATTRIBUTES_DEFAULT);
        nm.createNotificationChannel(nc);
    }
    Notification.Builder builder =
            null;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        builder = new Notification.Builder(this, "myteset");
}
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle(getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText("");
    startForeground(1000, builder.build());
}}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you tell me the crash log?
You can seach it with keyword "FATAL"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to record in your background,
you have to use Service with startForeground.
Because background service cannot use mic.

1. Added below permission and your service in AndroidManifest.xml

   `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />`

```
<service
    android:name=".MyService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true"></service>
```

2. Implement Service

   ```
    public class MyService extends Service {
        private final IBinder mBinder = new MyBinder();

        public MyService() {
        }

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            return mBinder;
        }

        public class MyBinder extends Binder {
            public MyService getService() {
                return MyService.this;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            initForeGroundService();

            // startRecord() -- your implement
        }

        private void initForeGroundService() {
            NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            NotificationChannel nc =
                    new NotificationChannel(
                            "myteset",
                            getResources().getString(R.string.app_name),
                            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN);
            nc.enableLights(false);
            nc.enableVibration(false);
            nc.setSound(null, Notification.AUDIO_ATTRIBUTES_DEFAULT);
            nm.createNotificationChannel(nc);

            Notification.Builder builder =
                    new Notification.Builder(this, "myteset");
            builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentTitle(getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .setContentText("");
            startForeground(1000, builder.build());
        }
    }
   ```
3. startService from your acitivity.

   ```
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class);
    startService(intent);
   ```

Now, your service will be alive, even if your app is destroyed

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. Could you please check my answer below? I cannot add it as comment because it includes a code.

Comment: For your information, I am testing on a phone mobile with this Android version : 7.1.1

Comment: Hereafter the logs:  `2021-04-01 21:38:30.936 1652-1652/com.example.testaudiorecord D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2021-04-01 21:38:30.938 1652-1652/com.example.testaudiorecord E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.testaudiorecord, PID: 1652
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method <init>(Landroid/content/Context;Ljava/lang/String;)V in class Landroid/app/Notification$Builder; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.app.Notification$Builder' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar)`

Comment: `at com.example.testaudiorecord.MyService.initForeGroundService(MyService.java:114)
        at com.example.testaudiorecord.MyService.onCreate(MyService.java:63)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3563)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap6(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1749)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6816)`

Comment: `at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1563)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1451)`

Comment: It seems it is failing in this line `builder = new Notification.Builder(this, "myteset");`

Comment: `@SuppressLint("NewApi")  
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)  
    private void initForeGroundService() {  
YOUR_CODE
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            nc = new NotificationChannel(
                    "myteset",
                    getResources().getString(R.string.app_name),
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN);
YOUR_CODE
            nm.createNotificationChannel(nc);
        }
        Notification.Builder builder = null;
            builder = new Notification.Builder(this, "myteset");`

Comment: Android Studio suggests to add this kind of lines (see below). It cannot be the cause?  `@SuppressLint("NewApi")  @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)`

Comment: I fixed this issue by using this code `NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "myteset");` instead of `Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this, "myteset");`